# What's the equivlent code for stringWithContentsOfURL using a NSURLRequest?

Tags: objective-c, networking, timeout, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString];
NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

But, I was reading online that I should probably be using an NSURLRequest instead if I want to add a timeout.  The first code works fine, but the second code always returns @""  (not nil, just "").  Anyone have any suggestions?

I also read that the NSURLConnection takes care of any sort of web compression that might be done whereas NSURLRequest won't handle that, so I thought I better just go for the more well rounded solution.
http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Oct/msg01921.html

```
    NSString *escapedUrlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *responseString;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] 
                             initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString]
                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                             timeoutInterval:5]; // 5 second timeout?

    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if(responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]){
        NSLog(@"Recieved String Result: %@", responseString);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Response String is null!");
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the error? If something went wrong with the connection then it may have a value in it.

Comment: I would suggest that you go for asynchronous network calls instead of using sendSynchrounousRequest. It's a little more code to write but it saves you from having to do threading to avoid locking the main thread. As a bonus it also makes it possible to cancel the request.

Comment: Good idea loomer, but I still want to put it in another thread because I believe that it will still block in the main thread if I don't.

Comment: Asynchronous network calls will never block the main thread. They are designed to _not_ do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the good suggestions. The code magically worked this morning, so I'm guessing my webserver went down or something last night.